# Missing package property files in war build

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, m2eclipse

Littered throughout my project are various property files located in packages that are not being included when the package goal is run from a Maven build.

Using the 0.10.2 m2eclipse plugin and the default "package" goal.

In the project:

```
src->main->java->mypackage->MyProperties.java 
src->main->java->mypackage->MyProperties.properties
```

In expanded war directory after the "package" goal is run:

```
target->classes->mypackage->MyProperties.class
```

-- no property file --

I'm trying to get the group to adopt Maven and resolving this issue is going to be a deal maker. Moving the properties files isn't going to be practical. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pascal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3354564/missing-package-property-files-in-war-build/3357084#3357084) is the correct maven way of doing things.

But some developers like to keep resources next to their sources (it's standard procedure in wicket, for example).

If you're going to do that, you will have to add your source folder to the resources:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, Seanizer. That was what I was looking for. 

I agree with Pascal, but this is a legacy application with a very deep package structure. Moving the resources (property files) to a parallel folder in the resources folder would not have helped project comprehension.

Answer (score 5):

Put your property files where Application/Library resources belong, i.e. in `src/main/resources`:

```
src/main/resources/mypackage/MyProperties.properties
```

And it will get copied properly.

Answer (score 0):

Me helped to check build path. The rpoperties of resources were excluded. When I included them again, the war got all property-files from resource and tomcat deployed correct.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. Solution was check Build Path of project at Eclipse. At "source" look for "yourProject/src/main/resources". The node "Excluded: **" here you remove the filter, apply and build again with Maven. Then enable the filter again and runs like a charme with all property-files.

Hope this helps